# Needs too many Images to build animations，but when I built apk, the apk is too big

Tags: android, animation

Android App，needs many Images to build animations，but when I built apk, the apk is too big.Is there any effective method to solve this problem?

Comment: that depends on which animation you do, how you are doing it, and what are the images.

Comment: With the given information, it is really hard to give any answer. Please add more information about your app, animations and images.

Comment: Try this -> https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size.html#reduce-resources

Comment: I used series of images to make a frame animation,And there are many animations with different serices of images,when I built apk, The apk was too big to upload to Market.